# Google sheets googlefinance query not working within if statement

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-finance

In google sheets the following formula works fine

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("Currency:" & H6 & I6) * G6
```

If I try to use it within a IF-statement it gives a parsing error.

```
=IF(H6! = "USD", GOOGLEFINANCE("Currency:" & H6 & I6) * G6, "fail")
```

Must be a syntax error, but I can't wrap my head around it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You used wrong operator. There is no `!=` like in Python. Use `<>` instead:

```
=IF(H6 <> "USD", GOOGLEFINANCE("Currency:" & H6 & I6) * G6, "fail")
```

Or just `=` if you meant equality check:

```
=IF(H6 = "USD", GOOGLEFINANCE("Currency:" & H6 & I6) * G6, "fail")
```

[image]

Comment: YES! Thanks. That is the solution. Switching too much between program languages I guess.